# Sorting the string lines in a txt file and then overwriting it with the sorted lines

Tags: python, list, file, overwrite

So basically I have a file that is something like this:

```
hi
my
name
is
```

and I want it to be (get sorted alphabetically):

```
hi
is
my
name
```

My code below stores the lines from the txt file into a list and then sorts it. It does what I want, but...:

```
with open ("3ex.txt","r") as f:
    new = []
    for line in f:
        stripped = line.strip("\n")
        new.append(stripped)

    new.sort() #sorts by letter
    print(new)

with open ("3ex.txt","w") as file:
    for k in new:
        file.write(file"[k]\n")
```

It doesn't overwrite it.
I tried first reading the file then writing in it. But I keep getting errors.

Yes I know its bad thing to do, but thats what Im asked to do.

Comment: @mypetlion no that's not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `new` list out of the with the statement. And also correct the `file.write` argument.
Here is the corrected code

```py
new = []
with open ("3ex.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        stripped = line.strip("\n")
        new.append(stripped)

new.sort() #sorts by letter
with open ("3ex.txt","w") as file:
    for k in new:
        file.write(k + "\n")
```

Comment: you don't need to define `new` outside of the the with statement. there's nothing wrong with doing so and it's arguably better stylistically, but it's not required.

Comment: omg I just need the k + "\n", like it worked for me with just file.write(k) but it was all smushed together. Im an idiot and thank you

Comment: Yeah, it is not required, but I am following the best practice of programming. Since `with` is a statement so it is local to it.